# Are there any impossible tasks, if every human's ability to concentrate gets halved?

Tags: science-based

If, because of some illness or whatever reason, every humans ability to concentrate gets halved, would any task, which is possible in our society, become impossible or could everything influenced by that be compensated with today's machines/ more time investment/ teaming up of several people etc.?

Image some insanely long, content heavy sentence. You have to concentrate to understand it. While in your normal state you understand it the first time you read it, you may need to read it more times under the conditions above, because you may have forgotten the beginning if you reach the end or you don't get the complex grammar on the first read etc.

Comment: What do you count as halving the "ability to concentrate", halved in time? Halved in actual ability?

Comment: Halved in actual ability. Image some insanely long, content heavy sentence. You have to concentrate to understand it. In the question above, you may need to read it more time,s because you may have forgotten the beginning if you reach the end or you don't get the complex grammar on the first read etc.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to address the issues raised in the comments.  Thise are notes to feedback to you (which can then be deleted), not a discussion forum.

Comment: What's a "long, content heavy sentence"? If a sentence such as *"Quoniam autem vivitur non cum perfectis hominibus planeque sapientibus, sed cum iis, in quibus praeclare agitur, si sunt simulacra virtutis, etiam hoc intellegendum puto, neminem omnino esse neglegendum, in quo aliqua significatio virtutis appareat, colendum autem esse ita quemque maxime, ut quisque maxime virtutibus his lenioribus erit ornatus, modestia, temperantia, hac ipsa, de qua multa iam dicta sunt, iustitia"* is too long one can always stop using Latin periods and switch to American English. (Cicero, _De officiis_, 1:46).

Comment: I've seens some laws, which contained single sentences, which were even longer than your example. But as they were german, it wouldn't make to much sense searching for them now.

Comment: The example was limited by the maximum length of a comment. And yes, in certain official styles long sentences are common. The point is that this is just a style of writing -- reading and comprehending a text depends finally on the conveyed meaning, not on the length of individual sentences. American English prefers short sentences, French (at least in high literature, law and philosophy) prefers long sentences, but in the end this is irrelevant; when reading such long French sentences one just has to take care to discern their structure. They are not inherently harder to read.

Comment: Please tell us exactly how you measure concentrating or that question doesn't make any sense. I'm not aware that there is any universally accepted way

Comment: Maybe check an ADHD forum to get rough answer what users have trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase the question: once this "illness" happens, what ability do we lose. OK, by whatever measure, we are half the species we were before, but some individuals would still have all the relative advantages of money and status, corporations would still participate in groupthink, and a genius halved is still a genius when everyone else is also halved. Society stays stratified and probably in the same order as before. Social institutions and governments would remain.

But in general, people would be more passionate. Quicker to anger. Fickle in love. Art and culture would regress to slapstick and teen melodrama. Politics and education would suffer, as well as engineering and science. It would be putting the breaks on innovation and social reform.

There would be more car accidents, job-related injuries, medical misdiagnoses. There's no way to put a number on it, but your mortality rate would soar.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably no *impossible* tasks, or more precisely tasks which cannot be completed *solely* because of a lack of concentration, but there are many tasks which would become much more difficult and even extremely dangerous.

Let us say, for example, I ask you to drive in a cab and heavy trailer.  I can probably teach you to do the driving despite your reduced concentration, although it might be more frustrating for both of us than with someone with better concentration.

But now let us say you must drive down a very long straight stretch of empty highway in the same cab with trailer.  This requires concentration and it's a fact, proven everyday by accidents, that *good and sober* drivers can loose concentration on these kinds of roads and find themselves nodding off and - bang - in a ditch in a moment.

So with your reduced ability to concentrate this becomes a much more dangerous task and one you are much more likely to find very difficult to complete successfully.

If I ask you to study for an exam in a subject that is mostly about memorization and repetition, this might be very difficult.  But not impossible.

I cannot imagine a task that you'd find absolutely impossible.

Lack of concentration does not prevent you starting a task or reacting initially to a situation (compare that with some other medical conditions), whereas it reduces your ability to be effective, *but does not absolutely prevent you from being effective*.

> could everything influenced by that be compensated with today's machines/ more time investment/ teaming up of several people etc.?

Training and teamwork are both effective ways to improve task completion in general.

Machines are provably better at monitoring tasks than humans (who are terrible at them).  This is one reason why the modern aircraft cockpit is heavily computerized - the computers can monitor basic operations far better (on average) than humans.

So machines can go a long way to help the sufferers of your reduced concentration in certain situations.